# "...at nightfall, tents are set up for sleeping in comfort." What type of phrase is "sleeping in comfort"?

Tags: grammar, phrases

In the following phrase:

> ...at nightfall, tents are set up for sleeping in comfort.

What type of phrase is *sleeping in comfort*?

I suspect it might be either a gerund or a participial. I think that the phrase modifies the word "set"

Comment: *Sleeping* is a gerund, an *-ing* form employed as a noun, and it is the object of the preposition *for*; the preposition phrase *for sleeping in comfort* modifies the clause *tents are set up*, describing the purpose behind this action.

Comment: Having spent numerous nights in tents, I would say "sarcastic".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that it is a gerund because if there is nothing the phrase it modifies and it starts with an -ed or -ing then it is gerund because it acts as a noun

however if it does modify something and it describes a noun it is a participial phrase